# using useparams and array.find to display detailed data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a small blog application using react js. I have a context api for the user inputs, so that the data can be used globally across components (InputContext.js). Using react router, the user is able to view a list of all blog entries (AllBlogs.js) and view each one of them in detail (BlogDetail.js). What I am trying to achieve is, allow the user to get a detailed view of an individual blog post component from the AllBlogs.js page. All blogs have an "id" property, which is used to query the url and using the array.find method, it is supposed to show a detailed view of the blog with the matching id. The problem is "findBlogs" in BlogDetails that is being passed as a prop to display the detailed individual blog data always only returns the most recent user input value, therefore all blogs show the exact same information. I am unsure as to why this is happening, any guidance towards the right direction is greatly appreciated.

InputContext.js

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useMemo } from 'react'

//create context
export const InputContext = createContext();

const InputContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [blogPost, setBlogPost] = useState({
        id: '',
        title: '',
        author: '',
        text: ''
    });

    //create an array to push all the blogPosts
    const [allBlogPosts, setAllBlogPosts] = useState([]);
    console.log(allBlogPosts)

    //put value inside useMemo so that the component only rerenders when there is change in the value
    const value = useMemo(() => ({ blogPost, setBlogPost, allBlogPosts, setAllBlogPosts }), [blogPost, allBlogPosts])

    return (
        <InputContext.Provider value={value}>
            {props.children}
        </InputContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default InputContextProvider;
```

WriteBlogPost.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext, Fragment } from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import { InputContext } from '../Contexts/InputContext'
import { TextareaAutosize } from '@material-ui/core'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { Box, TextField, Button, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        textAlign: 'center'
    }
})

export const WriteBlogPost = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const [blog, setBlog] = useState({
        id: '',
        title: '',
        author: '',
        text: ''
    });

    const history = useHistory();

    const { setBlogPost } = useContext(InputContext);
    const { allBlogPosts, setAllBlogPosts } = useContext(InputContext)

    const handleBlogPost = () => {
        setBlogPost(blog);
        setAllBlogPosts([...allBlogPosts, blog]);
        history.push("/blogs")

        console.log({ blog })
        console.log({ allBlogPosts })
    }

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value
        setBlog({
            ...blog,
            id: uuidv4(),
            [e.target.name]: value
        })
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Box className={classes.root}>
                <div>
                    <TextField id="standard-basic" onChange={handleChange} value={blog.title} name="title" label="Title" />

                </div>

                <div>
                    <TextField id="standard-basic" onChange={handleChange} value={blog.author} name="author" label="Author" />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <TextareaAutosize aria-label="minimum height" minRows={20} style={{ width: '70%' }} placeholder="Your blog post"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        value={blog.text}
                        name="text" />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleBlogPost}>
                        Submit</Button>
                </div>
            </Box>

        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

AllBlogs.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { InputContext } from '../Contexts/InputContext'
import { Card, CardContent, Typography } from '@material-ui/core'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        display: 'flex',
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
    text: {
        textAlign: 'center'
    }
})

export const AllBlogs = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const { allBlogPosts, blogPost } = useContext(InputContext)

    console.log(allBlogPosts)

    return (
        <div>
            <Typography color="textPrimary" variant="h3" className={classes.text}>All blogs</Typography>
            {allBlogPosts.map((post, i) =>
                <Card variant="outlined" key={i} className={classes.root}>
                    <CardContent>
                        <Typography color="textPrimary" variant="h5">
                            {post.title}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography color="textPrimary" variant="h6">
                            {post.author}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography color="textPrimary" variant="body2" component="p">
                            {post.text}
                        </Typography>
                        <Link to={`/blogs/${blogPost.id}`}>
                            Read blog
                        </Link>
                    </CardContent>
                </Card>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

BlogDetail.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { useParams, Route } from 'react-router'
import { SingleBlog } from './SingleBlog';
import { InputContext } from '../Contexts/InputContext';

export const BlogDetail = () => {
    const params = useParams();
    console.log(params.blogId)

    const { allBlogPosts } = useContext(InputContext)
    const findBlog = allBlogPosts.find((post) => post.id === params.blogId)
    console.log(findBlog)

    if (!findBlog) {
        return <p>No blogs found.</p>
    }

    return (
         <div>
        <h1>Blog details</h1>
        <SingleBlog post={findBlog} />
    </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what "all blog posts are shown as the most recent entry" means? This is a bit of a code dump, what specifically needs to be looked at? What is the issue? Can you also update your question to show your `Router` and routes? Additionally, why do you render another `Route` component in `BlogDetail`? It seems like it should render only a single blog entry, correct?

Comment: I updated the question for clarification, hope this is able to explain things better. The Route component in BlogDetail is there so that it can render the SingleBlog component, which takes in the params/blogId data from BlogDetail in order to render specific information about each blog using this information(the respective title, author, text).

Comment: Other than the extra route I asked about I don't see any overt issues in your code. The extra route isn't necessary since `BlogDetail` is already rendered on `path="/blogs/:blogId"` and passes the specific blog entry to `SinglePost`, i.e. `<SingleBlog post={findBlog} />`. It's not clear what you are saying the issue is.

Comment: "The problem is "findBlogs" in BlogDetails that is being passed as a prop to display the detailed individual blog data always only returns the most recent user input value" How is this so? `findBlog` result value is based on the `blogId` route param and not any user input. It's starting to sound like `allBlogPosts` provided from the context doesn't have the values you are expecting it to have. Can you share your context code and the related code that updates it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Ah, I see what is happening... had to dig back through your edits to when you included your context code.

In your provider you for some reason store an array of blogs (this part makes sense), but then you also store the last blog that was edited.

```
const InputContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [blogPost, setBlogPost] = useState({
    id: '',
    title: '',
    author: '',
    text: ''
  });

  //create an array to push all the blogPosts
  const [allBlogPosts, setAllBlogPosts] = useState([]);

  //put value inside useMemo so that the component only rerenders when there is change in the value
  const value = useMemo(() => ({
    blogPost, // <-- last blog edited
    setBlogPost,
    allBlogPosts,
    setAllBlogPosts
  }), [blogPost, allBlogPosts])

  return (
    <InputContext.Provider value={value}>
      {props.children}
    </InputContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const WriteBlogPost = () => {
  ...

  const [blog, setBlog] = useState({
    id: '',
    title: '',
    author: '',
    text: ''
  });

  ...

  const { setBlogPost } = useContext(InputContext);
  const { allBlogPosts, setAllBlogPosts } = useContext(InputContext)

  const handleBlogPost = () => {
    setBlogPost(blog); // <-- saves last blog edited/added
    setAllBlogPosts([...allBlogPosts, blog]);
    history.push("/blogs");
  }

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value
    setBlog({
      ...blog,
      id: uuidv4(),
      [e.target.name]: value
    })
  }

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

When you are mapping the blog posts you form incorrect links.

```
export const AllBlogs = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const {
    allBlogPosts,
    blogPost // <-- last blog updated
  } = useContext(InputContext);

  return (
    <div>
      ...
      {allBlogPosts.map((post, i) =>
        <Card variant="outlined" key={i} className={classes.root}>
          <CardContent>
            ...
            <Link to={`/blogs/${blogPost.id}`}> // <-- link last blog updated id
              Read blog
            </Link>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

## Solution

Use the current blog post's `id` when mapping to form the link correctly.

```
export const AllBlogs = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { allBlogPosts } = useContext(InputContext);

  return (
    <div>
      ...
      {allBlogPosts.map((post, i) =>
        <Card variant="outlined" key={post.id} className={classes.root}>
          <CardContent>
            ...
            <Link to={`/blogs/${post.id}`}> // <-- link current post id
              Read blog
            </Link>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```